# Regex replace number after string

Tags: c#, regex

I’m looking for a regular expression to replace the following parts:

Input:

```
(`0[],System.Func{`0,``0,``1})
```

Output:

```
(T1[],System.Func{T1,Tm1,Tm2})
```

Note: The increase of the number would be nice, but is not absolutely necessary.

Is there a pattern that can do this?

Comment: What does that string mean? It looks like tokens of some programming language isn't it? You need a parser for the language, not regex.

Comment: It’s part of an Xml file containing all Xml comments of a .Net assembly generated by VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
var txt = new Regex(@"(?si)\(`(\d+)\[\],([a-z]+\.[a-z]+)\{`(\d+).`{2}(\d+).`{2}(\d+)\}\)");
var res = txt.Replace(@"(`0[],System.Func{`0,``0,``1})", m =>
            "(T" + string.Format("{0}", (Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value) + 1)) +
            "[]," + m.Groups[2].Value + "{T" + string.Format("{0}", (Int32.Parse(m.Groups[3].Value) + 1)) +
            ",Tm" + string.Format("{0}", (Int32.Parse(m.Groups[4].Value) + 1)) +
            ",Tm" + string.Format("{0}", (Int32.Parse(m.Groups[5].Value) + 1)) + "})");
```

Output:

[image]